# How to exclude equal values from a query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT queue.first_dealer, queue.second_dealer, queue.status
FROM queue
WHERE queue.status = 3
AND queue.first_dealer = $user_id
OR queue.second_dealer = $user_id
AND queue.status = 3
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

But sometimes the first_dealer or the second_dealer can be the same, I want to skip to the next records if they are the same.

Comment: maybe the distinct option in the query would help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some parentheses in your WHERE clause, because of `[operator precedence][1]` between AND and OR. Group conditions that belong together, together, like this:

```
SELECT queue.first_dealer, queue.second_dealer, queue.status
FROM queue
WHERE queue.status = 3
AND ( queue.first_dealer = $user_id 
      OR queue.second_dealer = $user_id)
AND queue.status = 3 AND 
queue.first_dealer <> queue.second_dealer
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Even in cases where you don't strictly need the parentheses, it may result in more readable code if you do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT queue.first_dealer, queue.second_dealer, queue.status
FROM queue
WHERE queue.status = 3
AND (queue.first_dealer = $user_id OR queue.second_dealer = $user_id)
AND queue.first_dealer != queue.second_dealer
AND queue.status = 3
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parentheses in your `WHERE` statement:

```
WHERE queue.status = 3 and
      (queue.first_dealer = $user_id OR queue.second_dealer = $user_id)
```

If you don't want them to be the same, just add another clause:

```
WHERE queue.status = 3 and
      (queue.first_dealer = $user_id OR queue.second_dealer = $user_id) and
      queue.first_dealer <> queue.second_dealer
```